# Can I better architect this image detection bot?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to learn python by building an image detection bot for a 2d game.

The bot checks to see if it can find any one of a number of images within a cropped section of the game window. If it finds something successfully, this triggers the bot to move the mouse and click a button while logging what's been found into a text file.

I'm very new at this and this is very cobbled together code from a few different tutorials that I'm working my way through.

Have I made any obvious mistakes? Am I wasting significant resources/cycles with nonsense calls? Is there a much simpler way to detect images and send mouse clicks? And any other advice would be appreciated.

Please explain any suggestions rather than simply posting refactored code.

**Working Code Below**

For testing purposes change `'App'` to the literal name of an application, place some `png` images of the application in `C:\test\*.png` and make sure to change `crop = haystack_img_resized.crop((360,22,600,65))` to a relevant co-ordiantes of your application window that contain your images.

```
import pyautogui as py
import glob
import cv2 as cv
import os
import numpy as np
import pygetwindow
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab

os.chdir(r'C:\test')
avoid = glob.glob(r"C:\test\*.png")

# Load Images 
def loadImages(directory):
    # Intialise empty array
    image_list = []
    # Add images to array
    for i in directory:
        img = cv.imread(i, cv.IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2)
        image_list.append((img, i))
    return image_list

def videoLoop():
    # Grab Window and find size 
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('App')[0]
    x1 = window.left
    y1 = window.top
    height = window.height
    width = window.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    # Actual Video Loop, cropped down to the specific window,
    # resized to 1/2 size, and converted to BGR for OpenCV
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    (width, height) = (haystack_img.width // 2, haystack_img.height // 2)
    haystack_img_resized = haystack_img.resize((width, height))
    crop = haystack_img_resized.crop((360,22,600,65))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(crop)
    haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow("Screen", haystack)
    return haystack


def objectDetection(image_list, threshold, haystack, a):
    # Object Detection
    for x in range (0, a):
        for i in image_list:
            needle_img = i[0]
            needle_name = i[1]
            sliced_name = needle_name.split("\\")[-1]
            result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, needle_img, cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED)

            # Get the best match position
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)

            # Define top left and bottom right and threshold
            (H, W) = i[0].shape[:2] 
            top_left = max_loc
            bottom_right = (top_left[0] + W, top_left[1] + H)
            
            # If something has been detected click keep looking code
            if max_val >= threshold:
                cv.rectangle(haystack, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
                cv.imshow("Screen", haystack)
                keep_looking(sliced_name)

            if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                cv.destroyAllWindows()
                break             


def keep_looking(sliced_name):
    py.moveTo(1715,1000,0.1)
    py.sleep(0.01)
    avoidLog(sliced_name)
    py.click()    

# Log details of what we've avoided function
def avoidLog(needle_name):
    sliced_name = needle_name.split("\\")[-1]
    skipTime = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y - %H.%M.%S")
    # Print Avoided Details to terminal
    print("Keep Looking - Avoided: " + str(sliced_name) + " at: " + str(skipTime))   
    avoidLog = open('.Ships Avoided.txt', 'a')
    avoidLog.write(("Sccessfully Avoided something") + " at: " + str(skipTime))
    avoidLog.write("\n")
    avoidLog.close()    


#############################
#############################
###### MAIN BOT SCRIPT ######
#############################
#############################

# load images to detect 
ships_to_avoid = loadImages(avoid)

while True:
    window = videoLoop()
    objectDetection(ships_to_avoid, 0.92, window, 10)
```